# Numerically compute intersection of infinite line and rectangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rectangles

I'm trying to numerically compute where an infinite line defined by two points intersects a (finite) rectangle also defined by two points. Here's a illustration of the various ways that the line can intersect the rectangle:
[image: A diagram showing "No intersections", "One intersection", "Two intersections", and "∞ intersections"]
How can I determine the number and location of the places where the infinite line intersects the rectangle? I know how to do this [when the line is finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liang%E2%80%93Barsky_algorithm), but I can't figure out how to generalize that to an infinite context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea: [find out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560492/how-to-tell-whether-a-point-is-to-the-right-or-left-side-of-a-line) on which side of the line the four corners lie

- no corners on the line and

  - all four corners on one side: $0$ intersections
  - one corner on one side, three corners on the other side: $2$ intersections
  - two corners on one side, two on the other side: $2$ intersections
- exactly one corner on the line and

  - three on one side: $1$ intersection
  - one on one side, two on the other sides: $2$ intersections
- exactly two corners on the line and

  - they are diagonally opposite ones: $2$ intersections
  - they are adjacent ones: infinitely many intersections